# SQL - smallest A with the highest B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, min

I am very new to SQL. 
How can I do the following:

```
SELECT (min)A FROM Table WHERE *(highest)B*
```

I basically want the smallest A with the highest B.
If there are 2 A's with the same B I want a random A.

Comment: Why do you want a random A? Don't you want the smallest A with the same B? Can you show sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
select a
from t
order by b desc, a asc
limit 1;
```

You can select the entire row if you want.

Comment: I think you must use `order by b desc, a asc` - or highest `b` not guaranteed (where is applied before max() calculation!).

Comment: @Akina . . . I think the question parses either way, but your interpretation is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but you could use `TOP` to bring the first **N** rows:

`SELECT TOP 1 A 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY B desc`